# How to get the URL of a <img> that has been redirected?

Tags: javascript, html

How to get the real image url of a image that is redirected?

Example: `abc.jpg` is redirected to `def.jpg` using HTTP Status Code 302.

How to get the redirected `def.jpg` programatically?

```
<img src="abc.jpg" />
<script>
  alert(jQuery('img').prop('src')); // alerts abc.jpg but the real url is def.jpg
</script>
```

Regards

Comment: how it's redirected ?

Comment: Using http status code 302

Comment: @PeterRader have you tried `img.getAttribute('src')`?

Comment: Yes, it prints still `abc.jpg`.

Comment: Is the image on the same domain as the page showing the image?

Comment: @dave Yes, the same domain.

Comment: @PeterRader  Why was this marked as a duplicate?  You can get the actual source by checking the HTTP header.  The question that this duplicates also doesn't seem to have an answer that indicates that.  I will post the solution that works for me as an answer to the question that this apparently duplicates.

Comment: @PeterRader I've just found a workaround, try this script but on your domain or localhost http://jsfiddle.net/infous/53Layyhg/1/

Comment: @EricLease i saw your answer and will try it tomorrow. Its marked as a duplicate because i think this is a 100% duplicate, i am very happy if your solution would work and so i will upvote.